# Would a person adapted for super-speed be super-strong too as a side effect?

Tags: biology, super-powers

Or am I just overthinking it?

Maybe I should note that the character is like 76% magical entity, so maybe it can simply be handwaved, but I wanna check if I can blend in some science in there, too. To clarify, I am looking for a reason for him NOT to be super-strong, but if it's unavoidable then meh.

Comment: Neo in the Matrix can't lift a car but in Reloaded he flew across the street at mach 3, the sonic boom knocks all the cars into the air! Of course he can bleed! but somehow he doesn't seemed to need any heat shield maybe 76% magic helps explain it ;D

Comment: @user6760 Couldn't he? I mean, when he jumps up to fly he literally leaves a crater in the pavement. Agents certainly crush and flip cars just jumping off of them.

Answer (score 3):

They could be super light.

But in the regular sense of super speed, super acceleration is part of the package so if they had normal mass, they would have super strength and need to be super tough (or die).

The only physical way around super strength and toughness it is if their muscles were capable of very fast speeds but unimpressive accelerations. In which case they would need a lot of time to spool up, which is a problem when human limbs have limited ranges of motion so always need to change direction. So they would just seem like a normal person...unless on a bike maybe or swinging your arms in a circle?

But if magic entity? You can ignore it or make them super light if they have mass at all.

Comment: Exactly how physically tough would he need to be? Like if he were as fast as Type I on this chart according to the Superpower Wiki https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Peak_Human_Speed/Supernatural would it make sense for him to be Type I strength according to this page's chart as well? https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Peak_Human_Strength/Supernatural

Comment: @CAPichowsky It depends on how much he weighs and how quickly he can accelerate and decelerate. He needs to be able to not snap his bones, tear tendons or muscles, give himself concussions, black out, bruise, get pressure induced heart attacks or suffocation, not explode eyeballs, etc. It's mainly about acceleration. It only becomes about speed when you involve drag due to air and things like that.

Comment: @CAPichowsky Note that no vehicle made of any known material can survive decelerating from operating speed to standstill in the distances and time frames of human limbs. To do so at supersonic speeds would probably require unobtanium limbs. To accelerate on foot from stand-still to 600km (the low end of your Type 1 speed) over 20m, or to accelerate a limb the same way over 1m requires an acceleration of 13,778m/s^2 if the person weighs 160lbs/73kg person and their arm is 5% their body weight. That's enough force to lift 5 tons.

Comment: @CAPichowsky At the high end of your Type 1 speed, 6000km/h, the speed is 10x larger and the acceleration 100x larger and now he could lift 500 tons. For the most part, he wouldn't even feel bullets and shrug off cannon shells. The square relationship means that he's only Type 1 strength at the low end and very quickly gets into Type 2 strength.

Answer (score 3):

## Temporal Distortion:

If a semi-magical being has super-speed, the simplest way to achieve it magically and not physically is to distort the flow of time. The effect is one where the character experiences reality at a different pace, with their motions slogging through a thick atmosphere.

But while super-strength might make it EASIER to move even faster, the individual would be generating heat that would be hard to disperse, eating food that will be hard to consume (or possibly digest), and breathing air that will either be hard to breath or won't disperse from around the person and will tend to create a sort of anoxic effect the more they exert their metabolism.

I suspect the effect would be a bit like climbing a hot mount Everest, with overheating and "thin" thick air. You'd need to justify super-strength by magical means, and the metabolic consequences would be high. A "normal" super-strong being with "normal" super-speed would burn out from the consequences of using their muscles in such a super-speed environment. So pushing through the slow reality might seem putzy, but if time is distorted, it simply becomes a matter of exerting force over time, rather than vast amounts of force to overcome resistance.

I would see the difference like superman versus the Flash in the Justice League scene where Superman has just been revived. Superman is using the vast application of force to achieve his goals, while the Flash seems to shift the flow of time to move "slowly" to him, but insanely fast to others.